# Is mutex+atomic necessary to make this code thread safe, or is mutex enough?

Tags: locking, c++11, mutex

I have some doubts wether mutexes are enough to ensure thread safety of the following code example or if atomics are required. In short question is: Would making `idxActive` a regular `int` make this code thread unsafe? Or is code even with atomics thread unsafe? :(
If it is important, I'm on 32 bit x86, linux, gcc 4.6. Of course I presume that 32 or 64 bit makes no diff, but if there is any diff between 32 and 64 bit I would like to know.

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
static const int N_DATA=2;
class Logger
{
    vector<string> data[N_DATA];
    atomic<int> idxActive;
    mutex addMutex;
    mutex printMutex;
public:
    Logger()
    {
        idxActive=0;
        for (auto& elem: data)
            elem.reserve(1024);
    }
private:
    void switchDataUsed()
    {
        mutex::scoped_lock sl(addMutex);
        idxActive.store( (idxActive.load()+1)%N_DATA );
    }
public:
    void addLog(const string& str)
    {
        mutex::scoped_lock sl(addMutex);
        data[idxActive.load()].push_back(str);
    }
    void printCurrent()
    {
        mutex::scoped_lock sl(printMutex);
        switchDataUsed();
        auto idxOld=(idxActive.load()+N_DATA-1)%N_DATA; //modulo -1
        for (auto& elem:data[idxOld])
            cout<<elem<<endl;
        data[idxOld].clear();
    }
};
int main()
{
    Logger log;
    log.addLog(string("Hi"));
    log.addLog(string("world"));
    log.printCurrent();
    log.addLog(string("Hi"));
    log.addLog(string("again"));
    log.printCurrent();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this belong on codereview.SE?

Comment: You know that you have std headers `<thread>` and `<mutex>` nowadays?

Comment: @Kerrek SB-yeah, old habits die hard.

Comment: @DontCare this is a general programming question(mutexes and atomics ), unfortunately I phrased the title  makes it look like it is specific.

Comment: I assume this is just an oversight in the example code, but your `scoped_lock`s are temporary objects and only hold the mutexes during that one expression. You need to name them. (This is an unfortunately common mistake, been there myself as well...)

Comment: @JohannesD can you explain PLEASE(I have it in like 15 places in my code :( ). I thought that the point of the scoped lock was that it is RAII lock on mutex

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl - you have to *name* the lock, like `mutex::scoped_lock Lock(addMutex);` for it to stay alive. Otherwise it's a temporary object that just locks and unlocks immediately.

Comment: Oh, doh, tnx... so obvious now. :) And the scary part is that I think that there is no way for the compiler to issue a warning about this because it doesnt know that it is the "special temporary".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use atomic variables if all accesses to those variables are protected by a mutex. This is the case in your code, as all public member functions lock `addMutex` on entry. Therefore `addIndex` can be a plain `int` and everything will still work fine. The mutex locking and unlocking ensures that the correct values become visible to other threads in the right order.

`std::atomic<>` allows concurrent access **outside** the protection of a mutex, ensuring that threads see correct values of the variable, even in the face of concurrent modifications. If you stick to the default memory ordering it also ensures that each thread reads the **latest** value of the variable. `std::atomic<>` can be used to write thread-safe algorithms without mutexes, but is not required if all accesses are protected by the **same mutex**.

**Important Update**:

I just noticed that you're using **two** mutexes: one for `addLog` and one for `printCurrent`. In this case, you **do** need `idxActive` to be atomic, because the **separate mutexes do not provide any synchronization between them**.

Comment: I  dont want to be rude but are you 100% sure? Because like I said in my comments to ChrisWue answer I'm not sure that mutex ensures order of updates, AFAIK it only ensures that max 1 thread at the time executes that part of the code, not that new values are immediately visible. I googled the mutex specs found almost nothing and what I found-no mention of the atomicity.

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure. A mutex guarantees that any changes made to shared variables whilst the mutex is locked are visible to the thread that locks the mutex next. They would not be much use if this was not the case.

Comment: OK, cool. And again, this will sound arrogant of me, but do you have any "serious" links(standard, gcc documentation...) that specify this. I tried MSDNing my search and for C# mutex had no luck in confirming your oppinion. BTW my feeling is that you are probably right, but when it comes to stuff like this I want to be 100% sure,

Comment: Look at 30.4.1.2.1 and 1.10 in the C++0x standard draft N3242. An `unlock()` *synchronizes-with* a subsequent `lock()` on the same object, which implies the required visibility.

Comment: tnx, and please receive my apologies for bothering you, I feel like an idiot now, I just saw that you are the maintainer of the boost thread library.

Comment: No problem. Please not the edit to my answer: if you use two mutexes you still need the atomic.

Comment: BTW I know that this is not the scope of this question but do you see a way to do it with one mutex. I ask because the problem is that printing "takes a long time", and I dont want to create long queue, so that is the reason why i use 2 mutexes. One for "fast" switch , and one for the "loooong" printing and clearing.

Comment: One part your update omits is that even with `idxActive` being atomic, `idxActive.store( (idxActive.load()+1)%N_DATA );` is a serious problem and needs to be reworked to use `idxActive.compare_exchange_xxxxx()`. @NoSenseEtAl : The answer already addressed this, albeit backwards – the code is fine as-is if you use one mutex and make `idxActive` non-atomic.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl : Regarding the fast vs slow issue, output to a standard stream is guaranteed to be data-race-free for output of a single character sequence as of C++11. Consequently, you can have `printCurrent` write everything to an `ostringstream` and `cout << oss.str()` asynchronously and keep the actual output outside of the locked region.

Answer (score 1):

`atomic` is not directly related to thread safety. It just ensures that the operations on it are exactly what it says: atomic. Even if all your operations were atomic your code would not necessarily be thread safe.

In your case, the code should be safe. Only 1 thread at a time can enter `printCurrent()`. While this function is executed other threads can call `addLog()` (but also only 1 at a time). Depending whether or not `switchCurrent` has already been executed those entries will make it into the current log or they won't but none will be entered while iterating over it. Only 1 thread at a time can enter `addLog` which shares its mutex with `switchCurrent` so they cannot be executed at the same time.

<strike>This will be the case even if you make `idxActive` a simple int</strike> Mh, the C++ memory model only deals with single-threaded code — so I'm not too sure if theoretically it could break it. I think if you make `idxActive` volatile (basically disallowing any load/store optimization on it at all) that it will be ok for all practical purposes. Alternatively you could remove the mutex from `switchCurrent` but then you need to keep `idxActive` atomic.

As improvement I would let `switchCurrent` return the old index instead of recalculating it.

Comment: "This will be the case even if you make idxActive a simple int." But cant it be that different cores can have different versions of idxActive in cache or registers? So although mutex guarantees that only one can enter critical section making idxActive regular int could cause threads to fill the wrong data vector? Or am I wrong?